# Errors upgrading Confluent.Kafka Unit test Messages .NET Core

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

```
_failedResult = new Message<string, string>(Consts.Topic, Consts.Partition, Consts.Offset, Consts.Key, It.IsAny<string>(), default(Timestamp), new Error(ErrorCode.Local_MsgTimedOut, MsgTimeoutReason));
```

I am having trouble upgrading to latest Kafka as my unit tests are using the old message format. I can't seem to find the documentation listing how to properly format the message. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the message format on the current stable `v1.3.0` in `confluent-kafka-dotnet`:

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/v1.3.0/src/Confluent.Kafka/Message.cs

You produce in following way:

```cs
var message = new SomeDto();

var dr = await _producer.ProduceAsync(
    "topic-name",
    new Message<Null, SomeDto>
    {
        Value = message
    },
    cancellationToken);
```

Data included in your message like `Topic`, `Partition` are no longer part of the message (they are part of the Producer Config or Produce Method)